# Disambiguating resources with same predicate in JSON-LD

Tags: ruby, rdf, json-ld

I'm having trouble figuring out how to disambiguate resources that use the same predicate in advance. I'm an RDF novice, so please excuse my terminology: I'll try to explain what I mean with examples.

I have an `Interview` resource/model with a (simplified) context like this:

```
{
  "id": {
    "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier"
  },
  "interviewers": {
    "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor",
    "@type": "@id",
    "@container": "@set"
  },
  "title": {
    "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/title"
  },
  "interviewees": {
    "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor",
    "@type": "@id",
    "@container": "@set"
  }
}
```

My `Interviewer` and `Interviewee` resources have contexts like this:

```
{
  "id": {
    "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier"
  },
  "name": {
    "@id": "info:repository/ive/name"
  }
}
```

I then create a resource that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "06bad25f-83c1-4ee5-b055-0cb87d4c06be",
  "interviewers": [
    {
      "id": "b0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92",
      "name": "Somebody",
      "@context": {
        ...
      },
      "@id": "urn:uuid:b0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92",
      "@type": [
        "http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/ivr"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "title": "Interview with So and So",
  "interviewees": [
    {
      "id": "bd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b",
      "name": "A third person",
      "gender": "male",
      "@context": {
        ...
      },
      "@id": "urn:uuid:bd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b",
      "@type": [
        "http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/ive"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "@context": {
    ...
  },
  "@id": "urn:uuid:06bad25f-83c1-4ee5-b055-0cb87d4c06be",
  "@type": [
    "info:repository/interview"
  ]
}
```

Everything is good, and I can store this "object" to my repository (I'm using RDF.rb libraries). However, problems arise when I then try to extract the object and "re-serialize" it. For example (excuse the Ruby code),

```
query = repository.query(:subject => RDF::URI(uri))
JSON.parse(query.dump(:jsonld, :context => Interview.context))
```

These lines extract relevant statements from the repository, and then mash them into a JSON-LD "resource" with the appropriate context. However, both interviewees and interviewers are moved into the `interviewees` attribute.

Of course, this makes perfect sense, since both `interviewers` and `interviewees` are related to the `interview` resource with the `dc:contributor` predicate (they are only distinguished by their individual  types).

I need to make the `dump` process aware of the related resource types, but I don't know of any way to add that information to the interview's context.

I don't know if this is even possible according to the current JSON-LS specs. [This issue](https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/issues/247) seems like it might be relevant, but I don't really know enough about RDF/JSON-LD to know for sure.

I could use different predicates for `interviewers` and `interviewees`, but it doesn't seem like I should have to do so. Any suggestions?

Note: I've also asked this question at [answers.semanticweb.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20160628032901/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/26047/disambiguating-resources-with-same-predicate-in-json-ld).

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I've modeled my `contributor` relations in this way (where an `interviewer` is a `contributor` with a type `http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/ivr`) based on one of the the recommended ways for qualifying DC properties. For example, one can express a MESH subject on a resource like:

```
<rdf:Description>
  <dc:subject>
    <dcterms:MESH>
      <rdf:value>D08.586.682.075.400</rdf:value>
      <rdfs:label>Formate Dehydrogenase</rdfs:label>
    </dcterms:MESH>
  </dc:subject>
</rdf:Description>
```

Suppose I had:

```
<rdf:Description>
  <dc:subject>
    <dcterms:MESH>
      <rdf:value>D08.586.682.075.400</rdf:value>
      <rdfs:label>Formate Dehydrogenase</rdfs:label>
    </dcterms:MESH>
  </dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>
    <dcterms:LCSH>
      <rdf:value>Formate Dehydrogenase</rdf:value>
    </dcterms:LCSH>
  </dc:subject>
</rdf:Description>
```

I would like to be able to reference a `lcsh_subjects` "property", where `lcsh_subjects` represents those nodes that are related to the resource with `dc:subject` AND that have type `dcterms:LCSH`. However, I realize that I'm probably thinking about JSON-LD model the wrong way.

Comment: AFAIK the `"@type": "@id"` means in your context, that the property has a string type, and its value should be interpreted as an IRI. The `http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor` seems to be a type (object) and not a property name (predicate). So I think your context is flawed. But I am new in JSON-LD as well...

Comment: I guess the `@type` is the equivalent of `rdf:type` predicate and the `@id` is equivalent to the actual subject at least by the property definitions, but it is hard to find anything about this... :S

Answer (score 9):

You may be confused about the @id to use for both interviewers and interviewees. You've defined them both with the same @id, meaning that they are the same predicate. They are defined to be contributors to the resource, but there's nothing to make them distinct from each other. You may consider that what you mean by "interviewers" is a predicate that is a sub-property of dc:contributor, and the same for "interviewees". It might be better to choose an existing vocabulary that already has the notion of interviewers and interviewees. Alternatively, create your own vocabulary which defines the terms you need, and use this for creating context types.

You're also escaping the URIs used within your object (e.g., "http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier"), which might not yield what you want, just use regular URIs such as "http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier".

(Also, you  use an "info" prefix, which is undefined. And, it's not necessary to declare @context at every level).

For example, you might consider creating http://example.foo/my-vocab# and defining properties within that (using your own dereferencable IRI, of course):

```
{
  "@context": {
    "dc": "dc:identifier",
    "rdf": "URI:http:/www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "http://example.foo/interviewees",
      "@type": "rdf:Property",
      "rdfs:comment": "Interviewee",
      "rdfs:subPropertyOf": {
        "@id": "dc:contributor"
      }
    },
    {
      "@id": "http://example.foo/interviewers",
      "@type": "rdf:Property",
      "rdfs:comment": "Interviewer",
      "rdfs:subPropertyOf": {
        "@id": "dc:contributor"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You could then use this with the context of your object as follows:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier",
    "myvocab": "http://example.foo/myvocab#",
    "info": "http://example.foo/info#",
    "interviewers": {
      "@id": "myvocab:interviewers",
      "@type": "@id",
      "@container": "@set"
    },
    "title": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/title",
    "interviewees": {
      "@id": "myvocab:interviewees",
      "@type": "@id",
      "@container": "@set"
    }
  },
  "id": "06bad25f-83c1-4ee5-b055-0cb87d4c06be",
  "interviewers": [
    {
      "id": "b0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92",
      "name": "Somebody",
      "@id": "urn:uuid:b0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92",
      "@type": [
        "http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/ivr"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "title": "Interview with So and So",
  "interviewees": [
    {
      "id": "bd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b",
      "name": "A third person",
      "gender": "male",
      "@id": "urn:uuid:bd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b",
      "@type": [
        "http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/ive"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "@id": "urn:uuid:06bad25f-83c1-4ee5-b055-0cb87d4c06be",
  "@type": [
    "info:repository/interview"
  ]
}
```

(Also, check this out on the [JSON-LD playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/index.html?json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fidentifier%22%2C%22myvocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.foo%2Fmyvocab%23%22%2C%22info%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.foo%2Finfo%23%22%2C%22interviewers%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22myvocab%3Ainterviewers%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40set%22%7D%2C%22title%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Ftitle%22%2C%22interviewees%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22myvocab%3Ainterviewees%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40set%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%2206bad25f-83c1-4ee5-b055-0cb87d4c06be%22%2C%22interviewers%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22b0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Somebody%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22urn%3Auuid%3Ab0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fid.loc.gov%2Fvocabulary%2Frelators%2Fivr%22%5D%7D%5D%2C%22title%22%3A%22Interview%20with%20So%20and%20So%22%2C%22interviewees%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22bd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22A%20third%20person%22%2C%22gender%22%3A%22male%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22urn%3Auuid%3Abd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fid.loc.gov%2Fvocabulary%2Frelators%2Five%22%5D%7D%5D%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22urn%3Auuid%3A06bad25f-83c1-4ee5-b055-0cb87d4c06be%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22info%3Arepository%2Finterview%22%5D%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%7D&startTab=tab-nquads)

If you turn this into something like Turtle (try http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/), you'd get the following:

```
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<urn:uuid:06bad25f-83c1-4ee5-b055-0cb87d4c06be> a <http://example.foo/info#repository/interview>;
   dc:title "Interview with So and So";
   <http://example.foo/myvocab#interviewees> <urn:uuid:bd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b>;
   <http://example.foo/myvocab#interviewers> <urn:uuid:b0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92>;
   dc:identifier "06bad25f-83c1-4ee5-b055-0cb87d4c06be" .

<urn:uuid:b0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92> a <http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/ivr>;
   dc:identifier "b0c262ce-7eb3-47f2-b212-a0e71cca0c92" .

<urn:uuid:bd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b> a <http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/ive>;
   dc:identifier "bd6bb9ec-f417-4f81-af69-e3d191e3f73b" .
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I really appreciate your input. You're probably right that using distinct predicates is the best solution, but I've added a little more detail above. I apologize about the escaped URIs: the escaping was just added by the JSON pretty printer I was using.

Comment: "rdfs:subPropertyOf": {
  "@id": "dc:contributor"
 }
Is this the way to define a subproperty of something in JSON-LD? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Sub-properties are defined on a vocabulary/ontology, not a context. Of course, a JSON-LD context may include a vocabulary definition, but most often I see them defined in Turtle or RDF/XML. You define a subPropertyRelationship to another property using the `rdfs:subPropertyOf` predicate, so your definition of, say, "interviewers", by adding a relationship such as you specified. That makes it available to an inferencing engine, such as SPARQL Entailment Regimes. The linter also uses this information when validating.